# UnsupportedOperationException in OptaPlanner when trying to use .penalizeLong

Tags: optaplanner

I am getting
`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Impossible state: passing long into an int impacter.`

When trying to use `.penalizeLong` function from ConstraintProvider class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an `int` based score type, for example `HardSoftScore`. You can't penalize that with a `long` match weight.

You have 2 options:

Option A. If your match weights fit into the `int` type size, simply replace `penalizeLong()` with `penalize()`.

Option B. Otherwise, if you need to penalize with `long` match weight. Change the score type from `HardSoftScore` to `HardSoftLongScore` in your `@PlanningSolution` annotated class.